# Payload in 200 OK response to POST request

Tags: sockets, http, post, webserver, webclient

I'm writing a simple socket program that implements an HTTP server that can handle POST requests. I want my server to send a 200 OK response after receiving a POST request. My problem is, I don't know what the payload of the 200 OK response should be like. According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1, the body of 200 OK response to a POST request should be:

*a representation of the status of, or results obtained from, the action*

Could anyone explain what this sentence means? What is a representation of the status of the action? What should I include in the body of the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST generally means to create something, so you could send a response containing data from the newly created resource. Alternatively you could respond with 201 and no body.

Comment: Thank you! So, if my client is sending a POST request with, for example, this body:
field1=value1&field2=value2
then the server could send back a 200 OK with the same body?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the exact same as the body, but yes. However if they don't need to retrieve anything from the request then it may be better to use 201.

Answer (score 0):

It fully depends on the context. If it is some REST application the HTTP response might return a JSON with the id of a newly created resource. If it is some HTML form upload it will instead likely return a HTML page which somehow reflects the result of the upload, like the new status of the shopping card with the item added, a newly created blog post or whatever makes sense in the specific context.